# Splitting a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

When I split the string `"1|2|3|4"` using the `String.split("|")` I get 8 elements in the array instead of 4. If I use `"\\|"` the result is proper. I am guessing this has something todo with regular expressions. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Just pointing out--the amount of time this confusion took probably cost you more than you will save by using regular expressions (over just coding the damn thing) over your entire career unless you do a lot of shell scripting.

Comment: I never intended to use regular expressions..the damn API is using automatically.. what am I supposed to do then?

Comment: Unfortunately the `String.split()` method always uses regexes. There are more flexible APIs available, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right. `|` is a special character for alternation. The regular expression `|` means "an empty string or an empty string". So it will split around all empty strings, resulting 1 element for each character in the string. Escaping it `\|` make it a normal character.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. is & is also a special character?

Comment: @why: No it's not. See http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. You could use `\Q...\E` to make sure the `...` won't be interpreted as special characters.

Comment: @why should I tell you my name: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split a string without using a regex, I'd recommend the [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). It can split on fixed strings, regexes and more.

```
Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on('|').split("1|2|3|4");
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is `OR` in Java regular expression syntax, basically splitting `1|2|3|4` with `|` is equal to telling `String#split()` to "split this string between *empty OR empty*) which means it splits after every character you have in the original string.